# How to catch DB Error in Sub Job in Talend

Tags: oracle, talend

I have the below design in Talend I am catching the error when the component fails but if there is any error from DB like **Cannot Insert as Parent Key not found** **Cannot Insert into column col2 expected 15 but actual 16** it is not showing any error if the insert job is ran a subjob

[image]

If I run the Job **FACTDIM_COMBINE** I can see the error but if it is ran as Subjob I am not able see the error

Please help to get the DB error when it is run as **SubJob** also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `tLogCatcher` component in your job. This will log all the errors even in the sub jobs. Also enable die on error functionality in all the components where ever necessary